# ListView taking all the vertical space

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am working on a website using Flutter, but I have encountered a problem with ListView.builder. It's working fine until I try to scroll it down, then it takes all the possible space on screen. I also tried to create a ListView.builder in column and I had the same issue that the ListView was showing on the whole possible height.

main.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:kakadu_web/pages/shop.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
        home: Builder(
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
            double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
            return Scaffold(body: ShopPage(width, height));
          },
        ));
  }
}
```

shop.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/svg.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

import '../resources/values/colors.dart';
import '../widgets/buttons.dart';

Widget ShopPage(var width, var height) {
  return Container(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    child: Row(children: [
      SizedBox(
        width: 80,
        height: height,
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: AppColors.primaryBackgroundColor,
          ),
          child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start, children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
              child: RichText(
                  text: TextSpan(
                      style: GoogleFonts.josefinSans(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                          fontSize: 60,
                          color: AppColors.primaryIconColor),
                      children: [TextSpan(text: "M")])),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 200,
            ),
            PageSelectionButton(
              text: "Sklepik ",
              icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart_outlined),
            ),
            PageSelectionButton(
              text: "Sklepik ",
              icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart_outlined),
            ),
            PageSelectionButton(
              text: "Sklepik ",
              icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart_outlined),
            ),
          ]),
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12),
              child: Row(children: [
                Expanded(child: Container()),
                Flexible(
                  child: ListTile(
                    minVerticalPadding: 8,
                    selectedTileColor: Colors.indigoAccent,
                    selected: true,
                    title: Center(
                        child: RichText(
                      text: TextSpan(
                          style: GoogleFonts.rubik(
                              fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                          text: "Wszystko"),
                    )),
                    tileColor: Colors.indigo,
                  ),
                ),
                Flexible(
                  child: ListTile(
                    minVerticalPadding: 8,
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16),
                    selectedTileColor: Colors.indigoAccent,
                    selected: true,
                    title: Center(
                        child: RichText(
                      text: TextSpan(
                          style: GoogleFonts.rubik(
                              fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                          text: "Wszystko"),
                    )),
                    tileColor: Colors.indigo,
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(child: Container()),
              ]),
            ),
            Divider(),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 8,
                  ),
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) => Row(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
                          child: ListTile(
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius:
                                    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(60))),
                            leading: SvgPicture.asset(
                              "assets/drink.svg",
                            ),
                            title: RichText(
                                text: TextSpan(
                              style: GoogleFonts.rubik(
                                  fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                              text: "Tymbark Jabłkowy 2L",
                            )),
                            subtitle: RichText(
                                text: TextSpan(
                              style: GoogleFonts.rubik(
                                  fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
                              text: "20.00 zł",
                            )),
                            onTap: () => debugPrint("Przycisnął"),
                            tileColor: AppColors.primaryBackgroundColor,
                            trailing: Container(
                              width: 100,
                              child: Row(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                                  children: [
                                    SvgPicture.asset(
                                      "assets/sweets.svg",
                                      semanticsLabel: "Vege",
                                      width: 50,
                                    ),
                                    SvgPicture.asset("assets/cold.svg",
                                        semanticsLabel: "Vege", width: 50)
                                  ]),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ]),
  );
}
```

These are screens how it looks like:

[image]
[image]

ListView after adding SizedBox

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/svg.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

import '../resources/values/colors.dart';
import '../widgets/buttons.dart';

Widget ShopPage() {
  return Expanded(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12),
          child: Row(children: [
            Expanded(child: Container()),
            Flexible(
              child: ListTile(
                minVerticalPadding: 8,
                selectedTileColor: Colors.indigoAccent,
                selected: true,
                title: Center(
                    child: RichText(
                  text: TextSpan(
                      style: GoogleFonts.rubik(
                          fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                      text: "Wszystko"),
                )),
                tileColor: Colors.indigo,
              ),
            ),
            Flexible(
              child: ListTile(
                minVerticalPadding: 8,
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16),
                selectedTileColor: Colors.indigoAccent,
                selected: true,
                title: Center(
                    child: RichText(
                  text: TextSpan(
                      style: GoogleFonts.rubik(
                          fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                      text: "Wszystko"),
                )),
                tileColor: Colors.indigo,
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(child: Container()),
          ]),
        ),
        Divider(),
        Expanded(
          child: SizedBox(  // Here is created SizedBox
            height: 500,
            child: ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 8,
              ),
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
                      child: ListTile(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius:
                                BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(60))),
                        leading: SvgPicture.asset(
                          "assets/drink.svg",
                        ),
                        title: RichText(
                            text: TextSpan(
                          style: GoogleFonts.rubik(
                              fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                          text: "Tymbark Jabłkowy 2L",
                        )),
                        subtitle: RichText(
                            text: TextSpan(
                          style: GoogleFonts.rubik(
                              fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
                          text: "20.00 zł",
                        )),
                        onTap: () => debugPrint("Przycisnął"),
                        tileColor: AppColors.primaryBackgroundColor,
                        trailing: Container(
                          width: 100,
                          child: Row(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                              children: [
                                SvgPicture.asset(
                                  "assets/sweets.svg",
                                  semanticsLabel: "Vege",
                                  width: 50,
                                ),
                                SvgPicture.asset("assets/cold.svg",
                                    semanticsLabel: "Vege", width: 50)
                              ]),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Listview is expected to take all the possible height given by its parent. So if you expect to have a Listview with finite height you should create a SizedBox() with specific height and make Listview its child.

Here is a youtube video from Flutter team explaining this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jckqXR5CrPI

[image]

Comment: The thing is I tried this and still the same problem :/. Also I think that wrapping it inside Expanded as I did was enough, but I am not sure.

Comment: share your implementation using SizedBox

Comment: I have added updated code at the end of the post. The part where I put the SizedBox is commented.
I also exported the sidebar to the main.dart that shop.dart would be more readable, but that's not really important in this problem.

Comment: I think you are using wrong some widgets to create your "appBar", so, as your "appbar" widgets doesn't have any "body" listview items are shown over those items. I have created this dartpad as an example: https://dartpad.dev/?id=16e7c92106ecc5adf2fcb7a02f86a3df